# Como mejorar mi trigger

Tags: sql, trigger, update

Sucede que estoy desarrollando una aplicación a la cual tengo que crearle un registro de actividad, el cual ya lo tengo casi en su totalidad pero me cruce con un inconveniente.

A la tabla que tengo en SQL le agregue una columna donde registro los datos que contenía la celda antes de que se realice el "UPDATE" , creé un trigger para obtener esa información y aquí viene lo malo: el trigger es funcional y logra hacer lo que quiero que haga, pero a pesar de esto siento que no esta hecho de la manera adecuada y desearía saber una mejor forma de hacerlo, ya que al código que dejo publicado aun le falta agregarle 25 variables más y como lo veo no creo que seguir por ese camino sea la forma correcta de hacerlo.

Quedo agradecido con cualquier sugerencia que me puedan brindar.

```
    ALTER trigger [dbo].[CControl]
    
    on [dbo].[Estanteria]
    
    after update 
    
    as
    
    declare @C varchar(255),@CI varchar (255),@Id int,@Nc varchar(255),@NcI varchar(255),@B varchar(255),@BI varchar(255),@tP varchar(255),@tPI varchar(255),@Cj varchar(255),@CjI varchar(255),@I1 varchar(255),@I1I varchar(255),@I5 varchar(255),@I5I varchar(255),@I4 varchar(255),@I4I varchar(255),@I3 varchar(255),@I3I varchar(255),@I2 varchar(255),@I2I varchar(255)
    
    set @Id=(select top (1)ID from Registro_actividad order by ID desc)
    select @C=(select Consecutivo from deleted)
    select @CI=(select Consecutivo from inserted)
    select @Nc=(select Ncaja from deleted)
    select @NcI=(select Ncaja from inserted)
    select @B=(select BaseEnvio from deleted)
    select @BI=(select BaseEnvio from inserted)
    select @tP=(select tTipoFinal from deleted)
    select @tPI=(select tTipoFinal from inserted)
    select @Cj=(select Caja from deleted)
    select @CjI=(select Caja from inserted)
    select @I1=(select ID_1 from deleted )
    select @I1I=(select ID_1 from inserted)
    select @I2=(select ID_2 from deleted )
    select @I2I=(select ID_2 from inserted)
    select @I3=(select ID_3 from deleted )
    select @I3I=(select ID_3 from inserted)
    select @I4=(select ID_4 from deleted )
    select @I4I=(select ID_4 from inserted)
    select @I5=(select ID_5 from deleted )
    select @I5I=(select ID_5 from inserted)
    
    begin
    
    if @C!=@CI
    update a set Antelemento=@C from Registro_actividad a inner join deleted b on b.ID_1=a.Caj and a.ID=@Id
    
    if @Nc!=@NcI
    update a set Antelemento=@Nc from Registro_actividad a inner join deleted b on b.ID_1=a.Caj and a.ID=@Id
    
    if @B!=@BI
    update a set Antelemento=@B from Registro_actividad a inner join deleted b on b.ID_1=a.Caj and a.ID=@Id
    
    if @tP!=@tPI
    update a set Antelemento=@tP from Registro_actividad a inner join deleted b on b.ID_1=a.Caj and a.ID=@Id
    
    if @Cj!=@CjI
    update a set Antelemento=@Cj from Registro_actividad a inner join deleted b on b.ID_1=a.Caj and a.ID=@Id
    
    if @I1!=@I1I
    update a set Antelemento=@I1 from Registro_actividad a inner join inserted b on b.ID_1=a.Caj and a.ID=@Id
    
    if @I2!=@I1I
    update a set Antelemento=@I2 from Registro_actividad a inner join inserted b on b.ID_1=a.Caj and a.ID=@Id
    
    if @I3!=@I1I
    update a set Antelemento=@I3 from Registro_actividad a inner join inserted b on b.ID_1=a.Caj and a.ID=@Id
    
    if @I4!=@I1I
    update a set Antelemento=@I4 from Registro_actividad a inner join inserted b on b.ID_1=a.Caj and a.ID=@Id
    
    if @I5!=@I1I
    update a set Antelemento=@I5 from Registro_actividad a inner join inserted b on b.ID_1=a.Caj and a.ID=@Id
    
    end
```

Comment: Las preguntas acerca de _mejorar_ un código o script _ya funcional_ encajan mejor en [codereview.se] (en inglés). Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio, y lee [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](/help/on-topic). En este sitio, tu pregunta está basada en opiniones.

Comment: Que raro este trigger... qué ocurre cuando cambia más de una propiedad/columna? Sólo la última en ese listado se guardará? Por qué no guardas todo el `inserted` y el `deleted` como `json/xml` en una tabla especialmente hecha para auditoría? no nos dices el motor de base de datos, pero si usas SQL Server, por qué no usas [Change Data Capture](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16)? El título de la pregunta no le ayudará a nadie que tenga un problema similar al tuyo. Cámbialo.

Comment: Esto en qué base de datos es? Por favor [edit] la pregunta y añáde una etiqueta a la pregunta con el motor correspondiente :)

Comment: Si es un registro de actividad ¿Por qué estás actualizando? Se tendrían que insertar los datos con fechas de cambio para mantener el registro y no simplemente sobreescribir.

Comment: Si omití colocar el motor de bases de datos y estas en lo correcto es SQL SERVER, en efecto solo la ultima se guarda y hasta momento es lo que necesito y como dijiste al comienzo esta como raro y quería la opinión de expertos y tomare tu consejo y el de otros que sugirieron lo mismo cambiare la pregunta . gracias probare con change data a ver que tal

Comment: luis Cazares gracias por tu observación la parte de inserción de fechas y cambios de datos los realice aparte por cuestiones del aplicativo.